# How to clean PostgreSQL database created with Phoenix/Ecto

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm starting to play with Ecto trying to understand it. As expected I messed up (with the user model) and I get an error while running a migration:

```
(Postgrex.Error) ERROR (duplicate_table): relation "users" already exists
```

Now, I want to clean the database using the shell/PgAdmin III so that I can then fix my model and run migrations again.
I've set up PgAdmin but I'm not able to see any "user" table...
What's the best way of doing this (either with Ecto, PostgreSQL shell or PgAdmin)?

Comment: If all tables (views, sequences, ...) are owned by the same user, then `drop owned by foobar` is the quickest method (where `foobar` is the name of the Postgres user owning everything)

Comment: Done! Don't you want to make this an answer so that I can accept it? BTW do you have any Postgres admin guide you would recommend?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With [ecto](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto) you get some new mix tasks to your project to deal with the database. They might help you:

- `mix ecto.create` - create the database which is used by your repository as backend
- `mix ecto.migrate` - runs the pending migrations for your repository
- `mix ecto.drop` - drops the database

There are some more new tasks, but these three will fix your problem. Try `mix --help` for the other new tasks.
In your case: first run `mix ecto.drop` to drop the database, `mix ecto.create` to re-create it again and finally `mix ecto.migrate` to migrate the tables, and you are back at start.

I've setup some keyboard shortcuts to type these commands quicker:

- `mec` is a alias for `mix ecto.create`
- `mem` is a alias for `mix ecto.migrate`
- `med` is a alias for `mix ecto.drop`

Comment: This answers the "created with Phoenix/Ecto" part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If **all** tables (views, sequences, ...) are owned by the same user, then

```
drop owned by foobar;
```

is the quickest method (where foobar is the name of the Postgres user owning everything). This will really drop everything *owned* by that user regardless on how this was created. You also can't use this if for some reason you created everything with the superuser (typically `postgres`) - but you shouldn't use that for "regular" things anyway.